# How might I implement etcd's watch-stream functionality with RocksDB?

Tags: rust, etcd, rocksdb

I would like to duplicate etcd's watch-stream functionality in a Rust application which uses RocksDB. According to etcd's [documentation](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/learning/api/#watch-streams):

> Watches make three guarantees about events:
>
> Ordered - events are ordered by revision; an event will never appear on a watch if it precedes an event in time that has already been posted.
>
> Reliable - a sequence of events will never drop any subsequence of events; if there are events ordered in time as a < b < c, then if the watch receives events a and c, it is guaranteed to receive b.
>
> Atomic - a list of events is guaranteed to encompass complete revisions; updates in the same revision over multiple keys will not be split over several lists of events.

One approach I've considered is to combine [`latest_sequence_number`](https://docs.rs/rocksdb/0.21.0/rocksdb/struct.DBCommon.html#method.latest_sequence_number) with [`get_updates_since`](https://docs.rs/rocksdb/0.21.0/rocksdb/struct.DBCommon.html#method.get_updates_since), but that requires me to deserialize the [WriteBatch](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/de1e3ff6eab9bc562ef262b1a49ec002b7bbbaef/db/write_batch.cc#L10), and it's not guaranteed to work properly. For example, if the size of `get_updates_since` is zero, it could be because there have not been any updates to the key space, or it could be that a compaction has occurred. There does not seem to be a way to differentiate between those two states. In other words, I have no basis upon which I can return an error saying, "The provided sequence number is too old and has already been compacted".

I've also looked at [tailing iterators](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Tailing-Iterator), but the documentation states:

> Not all new data is guaranteed to be available to a tailing iterator.

Kubernetes [provides](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) this functionality by exposing etcd's `mod_revision` to clients. Is there such an equivalent in RocksDB?